# Laurent series for $\frac{z}{z+1}$ on $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

> Calculate the Laurent series for $\displaystyle\frac{z}{z+1}$ when $|z|>1$.

There is really no singularity here, right? Can I just use a Taylor series, or what should I do?

Comment: There is a pole at $z=-1$, right on the boundary circle.

Answer (score 3):

For $|z|\gt1$,
$$\frac{z}{z+1}=\frac1{1+\frac1z}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(-1)^n}{z^n}.$$
**Edit:**
For $|z|\lt1$,
$$\frac{z}{z+1}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^nz^{n+1}.$$

Comment: But in that series, if $z=0$ we have a problem, whilst in $\frac{z}{z+1}$ there is not.

Comment: Yes the series is not valid at $z=0$. More than that, it is valid at no point $z$ such that $|z|\lt1$.

Comment: How do I know then, which is which? I.e. how can I know when a Laurent series I define is for one range of $|z|$ and not for another?

Comment: One can start from the series and determine its domain of convergence.